# c# ThreadPool /WaitCallback - how to delegate in this case?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a program that shows its progress with different icons while working. The process is started by pressing the btnApply buton.

```
ManualResetEvent[] wait; 

    private void btnApply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        wait = new ManualResetEvent[1]; 
        wait[0] = new ManualResetEvent(false); 
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(doApply), 0); 
        WaitHandle.WaitAny(wait); 
        btnApply.Text = "Done!"; 
    }

    private void doApply(object dummy) 
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) 
        { 
            setPic(i, bmTODO); 
        } 
        // do something 
        for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) 
        { 
            setPic(i, bmWORK); 
            // do something 
            setPic(i, bmOK); 
        } 
    } 

    public void setPic(int i, Image img) 
    { 
        switch (i) 
        { 
            case 0: pictureBox1.Image = img; break; 
            case 1: pictureBox2.Image = img; break; 
            case 2: pictureBox3.Image = img; break; 
            case 3: pictureBox4.Image = img; break; 
            case 4: pictureBox5.Image = img; break; 
            case 5: pictureBox6.Image = img; break; 
            case 6: pictureBox7.Image = img; break; 
            case 7: pictureBox8.Image = img; break; 
            case 8: pictureBox9.Image = img; break; 
            case 9: pictureBox10.Image = img; break; 
            case 10: pictureBox11.Image = img; break; 
            case 11: pictureBox12.Image = img; break; 
            case 12: pictureBox13.Image = img; break; 
            case 13: pictureBox14.Image = img; break; 
            default: break; 
        } 
    }
```

With Win7 and 2 processors this works 'as it should'. 
But on XP I have to swich the task - but how can I do it in this special code? I don't want to specify each picturebox in doApply. 
I also tried with an delegate:

```
public delegate void setPicDelegate(int i, Image img);
```

But there was no satistying result: The program hangs or the icons are recently shown at the end alltogether.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're blocking the UI thread with: `WaitHandle.WaitAny(wait);`.  You need to allow the `btnApply_Click` method to end before the long running task has finished to allow the UI thread to handle new actions.

An easy way of modeling long running tasks in a UI context is to use the `BackgroundWorker`, as it will abstract away many of the issues for you.

Do all of the long running work in the `DoWork` event handler, and update your UI when the work is done using the `RunWorkerCompleted` event.  That event handler will run in the UI thread.  The class also has support for passing a result to the UI, handling progress changed information in the UI, and more.

Comment: But now I have a new difficulty:<br>
The BackgroundWorker has to open a new form, like a Message Box, but with much more complicated button texts. How can I swich to it?

`    r = myMessageBox("Message", "Caption");
..

private DialogResult myMessageBox(string a, string b)
{
    using (My3MessageForm myForm = new My3MessageForm(a, b))
    {
        myForm.ShowDialog();
        if (MessageSucceded)
        {
            return myForm.DialogResult;
        }
        else
        {
            return DialogResult.Abort;
        }
    }
}`
<br>
How can I do it?

Comment: @MartinS And what problem(s) do you have opening that form?

Comment: Sorry; beg me pardon. I tested it and it wouldn't function, but now I tested it again and it is very good as expected.

Comment: and why wont you mark this as an answer then? Servy spent some time free for you trying to help.. one click of a mouse to show you gratitude isn't that big an effort